# Azure File Storage - Block on copy

Tags: c#, azure, file-storage

I see that there is a `CloudFile.StartCopy()` method but how can I block until it's complete? This [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#copy-files) suggests calling `StartCopy()` and then calling `destFile.DownloadText()` which I assume would block but I don't want to redownload a potentially sizable file just to block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this answers the "Block" part, but this is something I have done in a similar situtation. I hope it helps.

```
   var target = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(targetItemName);

   // StartCopy will add a request to a queue, that's all
   target.StartCopy(source);

   // Now we poll the copy's status
   while (target.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
        await Task.Delay(500);

   if (target.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Success)
        throw new ApplicationException("Copy failed: " + target.CopyState.Status);
```